# echo php inside javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, echo

I need to get my MySQL php data array into JavaScript which utilises highcharts library.  I'm stuck at echoing some php within JavaScript that holds the data for charting.  so far i can echo the php into a format which I've tested and copied into the JavaScript and it works fine, but just need that little help in writing the JavaScript with the php..

php code: (I've included br/ tags so that it easy to look at)

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
    echo '{type: "column",<br/>';
    echo 'name: '.($i+1).',<br/>';
    echo 'data: [';
    for($j=0; $j<count($data); $j++){
        echo $data[$j][$i+1].',';
    }
    echo ']},<br/>';
}
echo '{
    type: "spline",
    name: "Strike Rate",<br/>';
echo 'data: [';
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
    echo $data[$i][7].',';     
}
echo '],<br/>';
echo 'marker: {
    lineWidth: 2,
    lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
    fillColor: "white"
}';
```

output of the php:

```
{   type: "column", 
    name: 1,
    data: [4,1,3,2,4,3,5,1,3,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,]},
{   type: "column",
    name: 2,
    data: [5,3,3,4,2,3,3,2,0,3,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,]},
{   type: "column",
    name: 3,
    data: [2,1,5,5,2,3,1,2,4,5,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,]},
{   type: "column",
    name: 4,
    data: [6,4,4,1,3,3,5,2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,]},
{   type: "spline",
    name: "Strike Rate",
    data:     [13.33,3.45,9.38,6.67,14.81,10.00,20.00,3.85,11.54,4.76,7.14,15.38,28.57,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,],
    marker: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
        fillColor: "white"
    }
```

I've tried `json_encode` and only echoing the php variables, but nothing I can do can make it work.

**UPDATE**
the answer was more simpler than just echoing PHP output into Javascript (I thought this was possible)...  Anyways, a BIG thank you to everyone who contributed, without such a great community I'd find it really hard to learn new things, find great advice and hints to correct the issues.

With the right advice, I was able to just create Javascript variables and use them accordingly.

```
<script>
...

var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($data[1]['data']); ?>; 
....
{
type: 'column',
name: '1',
data: myArray
},
....
</script>
```

Happy New Year too!
Cheers Steve

Comment: Why are you echoing `<br />` tags into JavaScript?  That's HTML, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with outputting data like this is reason for the error, it is very difficult to match up all of the braces. You appear to be missing a final curly brace and array braces around the entire thing.

Instead you could create the data structure and serialize it to JSON using the `json_encode` function which far less error prone. The code to do that for your case is as follows:

```
// Set up the columns
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i ++) {
  $column = array(
    "name" => $i + 1,
    "data" => array()
  );
  for($j = 0; $j < count($data); $j ++) {
    $column["data"][] = $data[$j][$i + 1];
  }
  $arr[] = $column;
}

// Set up the spline
$spline = array(
  "type" => "spline",
  "name" => "Strike Rate",
  "data" => array();
);
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i ++) {
  $spline["data"][] = $data[$i][7];
}
$arr[] = $spline;

// Output json
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: hay mate thanks a bunch!  it's nearly dead on perfect for the output needed for the highcharts.js i'll have a crack tomorrow morning to get this working, but what you've provided is great!

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing PHP, JavaScript and HTML which ends up in a complete mess. Here is an example how you can create a JavaScript object literal with PHP:

```
<?php

$values = array();

for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $value = array(
        'type' => 'column',
        'name' => $i + 1,
        'data' => array()
    );
    for ($j=0; $j < count($data); $j++){
         $value['data'][] = $data[$j][$i+1];
    }
    $values[] = $value;
}
?>

<!-- HTML stuff here -->

<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($values); ?>;
    // JavaScript that processes `data` here
</script>

<!-- More HTML here -->
```

The idea is:

- Build your data structure first, using arrays of arrays.
- Use `json_encode` to convert the array into JSON which is also a valid object literal in JS.
- Embed PHP into HTML or JS, don't generate (manually) HTML or JS.

---

I don't know in which format the data has to be, but I leave this for you to find out. Iterating over and extracting the data can probably be improved as well, but since we don't know what data you have, this has to suffice now.

Comment: thanks felix, i'm using your and stuart's suggestions... i'll report back soon!  thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your problem is with this kind of line:

```
data: [6,4,4,1,3,3,5,2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,]},
```

remove the trailing , in the array to have

```
data: [6,4,4,1,3,3,5,2,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
```

hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 1):

Another best way to deal the PHP array in javascript is [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

pass json encoded array to javascript from your php like

```
json_encode($result_array);
```

and process the json data in js using jquery. It will be easy than what you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Please store php value in hidden field and give some ID to that field & access value by using that ID in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an extra comma at the end of that data column. That would break the JSON. Use the implode function.

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
  echo '{type: "column",<br/>';
  echo 'name: '.($i+1).',<br/>';
  echo 'data: ['
  echo implode(',', $data);
  echo ']},<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=array();
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
$data['type']="column";
for($j=0; $j<count($data); $j++){
 $data['data'][] = $data[$j][$i+1];
}
}
json_encode($data);
```